# Sitecore 10.3 XC0 Docker - "The container operating system does not match the host operating system"

Tags: sitecore-commerce, docker

- `OS: Windows 11 22H2 22621.963`
- `Docker version 20.10.21, build baeda1f`
- `Docker Desktop 4.15.0 (93002)`

I downloaded the `10.3 XC SDK` container files. I ran the `ComposeInit.ps1` for the `xc0 topology` without any issues. I pulled all the images without any issues. When I go to run `docker-compose up -d` I get the following errors:

[image: Error message]

For the `ComposeInit.ps1` I supplied the following parameters:

```
-Topology "xc0" -LicenseXmlPath "C:\Sitecore\license.xml" -SitecoreAdminPassword "Password123$" -SqlSaPassword "S1t3c0reL0c4l"
```

I was able to run `XP0` and `XP1` without any issues. Does anyone know how to make `XC0` work?

UPDATED: Here is a picture of the images pulled. All are showing 10.3-ltsc2019 except the bottom 4 which appear to be the ones erroring. Maybe the XC0 config is setup to pull the wrong images?

[image]

Comment: did you switch to the windows container in docker? docker should show a switch to Linux containers... option - https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZ8od.png

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows Containers. I literally deleted the pulled images from my XP0 (working) and did the installation steps for XC0 and it did not work.

Comment: Are you running process isolation?  If so, switch it to hyper-v

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Windows 11 only supports hyper-v isolation for containers at this time. The comment from Mark Cassidy led me to revisit the installation instructions where I found this information on a Microsoft link:

[image]

Sitecore, if you are reading this, you should really add a note to your installation instruction to switch isolation mode if using Windows 11. Windows 10 does show support for both hyper-v and process isolation on Windows Server 2019 containers.

Comment: You, and your project team, will generally always be better off using Hyper-V over processs isolation.